# Insert data into Access database with visual studio 2012

Tags: basic

I'm trying to insert data into Oradores Table in Access using Visual Basic. The code I have is:
        'Public Variables
        novo_nome_comum = TxtNComum.Text
        novo_nome_completo = TxtNCompleto.Text
        nova_morada = TxtMorada.Text
        nova_localidade = TxtLocalidade.Text
        novo_codpostal = TxtCPostal.Text
        novo_tel1 = TxtTel1.Text
        novo_tel2 = TxtTel2.Text
        novo_tlm1 = TxtTlm1.Text
        novo_tlm2 = TxtTlm2.Text
        novo_email1 = TxtMail1.Text
        novo_email2 = TxtMail2.Text
        nova_cong = TxtCong.Text
        'End of Public Variables

```
    Dim connect As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;" & "Data Source =C:\Users\Fernando\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Agenda_DP\Agenda_DP\AgendaDP.accdb")

    connect.Open()

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = connect.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Oradores (NomeComum, NomeCompleto, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal, Telefone, Telefone2, Telemovel, Telemovel2, email, email2, Congregacao) VALUES('novo_nome_comum', 'novo_nome_completo', 'nova_morada', 'nova_localidade', 'novo_codpostal', 'novo_tel1', 'novo_tel2','novo_tlm1', 'novo_tlm2', 'novo_email1', 'novo_email2', 'nova_cong')"


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    connect.Close()
```

However, this is not working, and I don't understand why.
I searched in MSDN and I'm copying the example quoted to my code.
Is there anyone who could give me an hand?
Thanks in advance.

Fernando Pessoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will share you a piece of code:

```
Try
    Dim con As New   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=yourDB.accdb;")
    Dim cb As String = "insert into Table1 (Date1, Sample1) VALUES (@p1, @p2)"
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = cb
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString())
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Me.TextBox1.Text)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(Err.Description)
End Try
```

It is working fine in my sample.

You can visit a post called [MS Access - VB .net - connect and operate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/178479c8-befa-4d7e-a341-afd35815230d/ms-access-vb-net-connect-and-operate)